# Precise timeago

Tags: python, time, timeago

How to get precise time ago from timestamp / date

For example:

```
date = "2021-05-10T12:10:41"
```

And the response is:

```
1 month 10 days ago
```

Instead of

```
1 month ago
```

When using `timeago` package

Note: I used ISO timestamp because that's the response from API, I can easily convert it if needed.

Comment: You could easily convert what to what?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [dateutil-relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

>>> relativedelta.relativedelta(datetime.now(), datetime.strptime("2021-05-10T12:10:41", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
relativedelta(months=+1, days=+19, hours=+1, minutes=+13, seconds=+32, microseconds=+86719)
```

If you want to represent the above output as a string, you could try a custom function like so:

```
def time_before_now(isodate):
    r = relativedelta.relativedelta(datetime.now(), datetime.strptime(isodate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
    if r.months < 0:
        return f"{r.days} days"
    elif r.months == 1:
        return f"1 month and {r.days} days"
    else:
        return f"{r.months} months and {r.days} days"

>>> time_before_now("2021-05-10T12:10:41")
'1 month and 19 days'
```